# SQL database won't update value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, constants

When I run command in **.js program** it won't update in **SQL database**. Ex: `!sendmoney @blah 10000` sends the same values it didn't add or subtract from where I wanted.

```
con.query(`SELECT money FROM account WHERE ID in (${target.id}, ${message.author.id})`, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        const money = rows[0].money;

        if (args[1] > money) {
            return message.channel.send('You dont have that much cash on you.');
        }

        const give = (+money) + +(args[1]);
        const take = (+money) - +(args[1]);


        const sql = `UPDATE account SET money = '${give}' WHERE id = '${target.id}'`;
        const sql2 = `UPDATE account SET money = '${take}' WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`;

        con.query(sql, sql2);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are getting one balance (of, I assume, two returned) with ```money = rows[0].money;``` and then setting both ```give``` and ```take``` based upon that (```money``` will be one of the two balances; which one is pretty much random). You need to process the two balances seperatly so rather than ```money``` you need something like ```targetBalance``` and ```authorBalance``` (assuming I am understanding your aim correctly).

Comment: Not an answer but some hints:
- Should use a transaction to make it atomic
- Which flavor of SQL are you using? 
- The arithmetic can be embedded in SQL directly
- Where is `args` defined? Please embed a whole code sample
- Is auto-commit turned on? Maybe the script already works fine but the DB just doesn't commit the changes